# shell command using variable with spaces

Tags: vba, shell, pdf

```vb
Public Sub test()

Dim path As String
path1 = "C:\File Folder\File Test.pdf"
path2 = "C:\FileFolder\FileTest.pdf"
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuance\PDF Professional 8\bin\GaaihoDoc.exe " & path1, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

The above code in VBA works if the `path2` variable is used instead of `path1`, because of the spaces in the `path1` variable. How can it be fixed to run the variable `path1`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can improve the readability of your question by putting your code in a code block. You can highlight it all and click the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: Paths with spaces need to be quoted with double-quotes.  You can escape the quotes by doubling them up.  `path1 = """C:\File Folder\File Test.pdf"""`

Comment: wow!..it worked thanks to you....although I tried it in my failed attempt to do the double quotes..unfortunately, I did it with 2 pairs of those quotation marks...again thank you!

Comment: @Tim Williams, are you able to do this in a variable too...like """& path1"""..?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Paths with spaces need to be quoted with double-quotes. 
Escape the quotes by doubling them up:

```
path1 = "C:\File Folder\File Test.pdf"
Shell """C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuance\PDF Professional 8\bin\GaaihoDoc.exe"" """ & path1 & """", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: amazingly brilliant...it's so easy for you to solve issues like that...while for me it takes a day...or so and that is with your help....deeply appreciate your assistance..thank you very much, @Tim Williams...!